# Routing Error in Rails No route matches {:action=>"ticket_action", :controller=>"tickets"}

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is an error I can not seem to figure out I believe I have it routed. This is the error

No route matches {:action=>"ticket_action", :controller=>"tickets"}

I get this error after this code

```
<h4>New Action</h4>
<% form_tag :action => 'ticket_action' do %>
<p><b>Description</b><br/>
    <%= text_area 'description', 'description', 'rows' => 5 %><br/>
    User: <%= select("actUser", "user_id", User.find(:all).collect{|u| [u.name, u.id] } )%>
    <% end %>
```

I have this on my ticket_controller.rb is that the proper placement for that

```
#action
def ticket_action
  @act = Action.new(
        "ticket_id" => flash[:ticket_id],
        "description" => params[:description]['description'],
        "user_id" => params[:actUser]['user_id']
    )


routes
    actions GET    /actions(.:format)          actions#index
            POST   /actions(.:format)          actions#create
 new_action GET    /actions/new(.:format)      actions#new
edit_action GET    /actions/:id/edit(.:format) actions#edit
     action GET    /actions/:id(.:format)      actions#show
            PUT    /actions/:id(.:format)      actions#update
            DELETE /actions/:id(.:format)      actions#destroy
    tickets GET    /tickets(.:format)          tickets#index
            POST   /tickets(.:format)          tickets#create
 new_ticket GET    /tickets/new(.:format)      tickets#new
edit_ticket GET    /tickets/:id/edit(.:format) tickets#edit
     ticket GET    /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#show
            PUT    /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#update
            DELETE /tickets/:id(.:format)      tickets#destroy
      users GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
    clients GET    /clients(.:format)          clients#index
            POST   /clients(.:format)          clients#create
 new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)      clients#new
edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format) clients#edit
     client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#show
            PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#update
            DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to post the route to debug this problem, your route may refer to tickets yet your class is ticket. 
You should look into restful routes, especially given your use case. It seems you should really have an actions controller (ActionsController, named controllers/actions_controller.rb) and then post to the create action and provide a restful route (resources :actions)
My suggestion would be to read up on rest and rails first.

Additionally the flash isn't where you should store your ticket_id, ideally you should retrieve it in your actions controller's create action by posting to /action/ticket_action/1 and retrieving the id by accessing params[:id] in the controller. If you really must, store it in the session (session[:ticket_id] = "1") but 'rest' is where you should be headed. The flash will be removed and should only be set in the controller and then displayed on the next page, it will be deleted thereafter.

Update: ok thanks for posting your routes.

You can add the missing route like this if you want:

```
resources :tickets do
  member do
    post 'ticket_action'
  end
end
```

But it would be better to follow this pattern:

In actions controller:

```
def new
  @action = Action.new
end
```

Your form should look a bit like this, Rails will know to post to actions#create because @action is a new record (you can check @action.new_record? if you want)

```
<%= form_for @action do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 5 %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ticket_id, flash[:ticket_id] %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, User.find(:all).collect{|u| [u.name, u.id] } %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your actions controller:

```
def create
  @action = Action.new(params[:action])
end
```

or with less magic:

```
def create
  @action = Action.new(:user_id => params[:action][:user_id],
                    :description => params[:action][:description],
                    :ticket_id => params[:action][:ticket_id])
  if @action.save
    redirect_to actions_path(@action, :notice => "Created action")
  else
   render :new # any errors will be in @action.errors
  end
end
```

You should really be setting the ticket_id in the actions controller's new method though.

```
def new
  @action = Action.new(:ticket_id => params[:ticket_id])
end
```

And then in your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :ticket_id %>
```

Comment: I posted my routes and I do have an Actions controller  Helpdesk::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :actions


  resources :tickets


  resources :users


  resources :clients

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be "tickets_controller.rb", plural.